# slide transition is expanding the viewport width - framer motion

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I'm using tailwindCSS along with framer motion to add styles and transitions/animation to my project. The page contains several sections within which the items are displayed either in grid or flex format, in one of the sections where the items are displayed as grid items, I want one of the child items to slide in from the right side when it is visible in the viewport, my current code works, however when the item is sliding from the right, a horizontal scrollbar is created which essentially is expanding the viewport instead of keeping the item outside the viewport when not visible.

```
             <section>
                <div className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 p-3'>


                    <div className='visuals'>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dumb text</p>
                    </div>

                    <motion.div
                        initial="hidden"
                        whileInView="visible"
                        viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.5 }}
                    >
                        <motion.div
                            variants={{
                                visible: {
                                    x: 0,
                                    transition: {
                                        duration: 0.5
                                    }
                                },
                                hidden: { x: 500 }
                            }}>

                            <p className='text-2xl font-semibold'>Anytime. Anywhere</p>
                            <p className='text-xl'>Access and watch your favorite shows anytime, anywhere.</p>
                        </motion.div>
                    </motion.div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

As you can see, in the `hidden` property of the `variants` prop, I've set the value of `x` to 500, which is outside the viewport. But strangely, when I try the sliding transition from the left side, i.e, x -500 to 0, it works as expected without expanding the viewport width.
I'm unable to reason the cause of this issue, nor able to find any workaround.

Comment: To repositioned element is making the page wider, so it scrolls.
Setting `overflow:hidden` on one of the parent containers should fix it.

Comment: @Cadin, great, it works. Setting the `overflow:hidden` particularly on the parent container did fix the issue. Thanks.